# Js errors in wp-admin

Tags: wp-admin, javascript

I have a lot of js errors in wp-admin and, for example, I can't see visual composer in post or pages, I can't add a box to a widget, etc.
I got that errors in all wp-admin pages.
I updated wp and all plugins but nothing.

How can I solve that?

Thanks
Ale

[image: My js errors]

Answer (score 0):

I've seen something similar to this but your situation may be different. In my particular situation, the server did not have enough resources to use Visual Composer and support all the visitors on the site. Try to make your updates at a time when you have the least amount of active visitors and you might have more luck. You can also reach out to your hosting company and ask if you are maxing out your server resources. If your hosting company gives you access to cpanel or something similar, you might be able to look this up on your own. Good Luck!

Comment: Thanks to your reply.
I checked on cpanel...Disk usage 74%, Bandwidth 26%, MySql Disk Usage 9%, Server Load  1.14 (4 cpus), Memory Used  34.65 %

Comment: I tried to disable all plugins...only one error remained: TypeError: e is undefined wp-auth-check.min.js:1:1538

Comment: The other errors went away because deactivating the plugins deactivated the code that was causing them. The last error may be theme related. Your admin pages and posts are probably loading much faster if I had to guess. If you turn them back on one at a time you'll be able to narrow down the errors related to each plugin. In my experience, VC has been known to be problematic in particular situations. I'd still recommend reaching out to your hosting provider and asking about your server resources.

Answer (score 0):

Disable your plugins one by one and keep watching the errors to see if they disappear or not. it is possible that one of your plugins has been corrupted.
Also, make sure you have https:// on your urls because if you don't and your site is forcing SSL you might get some errors like that.